# Watchlist at stackexchange?

Tags: discussion

Sorry, for asking here. I know it is the wrong place. I am new to Stackexchange. I wanted to ask at the meta page (that is where the help button lead me). But over there I need 5 point, which I do not have.
I have searched the help pages but I have not found a hint. My question is:

Is there something like a "watchlist" at Stackexchange, where I can add questions I am interested in and get noticed if one of those question gets an answer?

Sorry^2: I had to add an invalid tag to post this question. :-(

---

Thanks for helping me and moving this post to the right place.

Comment: at the bottom right of the question page, you find a "question feed" button to which you can subscribe with an rss reader. the right place to ask would have been [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), where you might already have found an [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=subscribe)

Comment: you will also be notified about answers to question that you have marked as favorite.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suitable on [Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Flagging the mods for consideration of migration to Meta SE.

Comment: Click the star underneath the score on the question to add it to your watchlist, then go to the favourites tab on your user page to see which questions are in your watchlist.

Comment: See first: 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work

Then: 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox